# Python - Calling a function from a class

Tags: python, class, function

I'm having some trouble calling a function which is within a class in python.

Here is my folder hierarchy.
~/Code/program/main.py
~/Code/program/dc_functions/dcfunc.py
~/Code/program/dc_functions/**init**.py

Basically, I want to use a function from dcfunc.py inside of main.py. How would I do this?

Relevant contents of dcfunc.py:

```
import subprocess, string, os, sys

class dcfunc:
    #Create raw Audio track(Part of Dreamcast Disc format) + Burn track to disk.

    def __init__(self):
        self.self = "self"  

    def burnaudiotrack(device):
        **CODE***
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Please, take a look to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Also, `self.self = "self"` doesn't have sense.

And `def burnaudiotrack` should have as first argument `self`.

You are saying that you want to use a function from `dcfunc.py`, are you sure? Probably you want to call a **method** instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your init.py file to be named `__init__.py`

then use

```
from dc_functions.dcfunc import function_name
```

And you'll have acccess to the function.

Comment: When I try to import it like that, then try to use it, I get a NameError. Do I just call it as if it were local? For example : function()

Comment: Yes. You're importing the name directly into the local namespace, so you can call it directly.

Comment: 'from dc_functions.dcfunc import *' This is what I added into my main.py. When I try to call any function within it from main.py, the interpreter tells me the name is not defined. Maybe something in __init__.py is wrong. I have "import dcfunc" there, and nothing else.

Comment: File "./main.py", line 44, in <module>
    burn()
NameError: name 'burn' is not defined

Comment: You have all of the functions in that file inside a class. In order for what I told you to work they have to be outside of the class. The class in that file doesn't make any sense. Probably you should just take all of the methods out of the class.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I was told you had to use a class, so you've cleared up a lot of stuff that didn't make sense. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sinthet, I should have paid more attention to your question, it clearly has the class in there. But your welcome for the help.